# Average number of days since first deposit since a withdraw. e.g, for a withdraw on 2022-07-25 the first deposit is on 2022-07-26 and duration is 1

Tags: sql

Input:

| userid | event | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wdr | 25/7/22 |
| 1 | dep | 25/7/22 |
| 1 | dep | 24/7/22 |
| 1 | wdr | 24/7/22 |
| 1 | dep | 24/7/22 |

Output:

| userid | wd_date | dp_date | duration_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25/7/22 | 24/7/22 | 1 |
| 1 | 24/7/22 | 24/7/22 | 0 |

Comment: Title says you want an average. What if there are two withdrawals without a deposit between?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".